# Arduino Infinity Loop

Tags: programming

I'm new to this Arduino programming. So I want to ask about my current project. My lecturer told me to make a temperature sensor using an LM35, where a green LED will light up when below some certain temperature that I set. The same goes for yellow and red LEDs for medium, and high temperatures. The tricky part here is that I need to make sure my buzzer (piezo) is on forever if it reaches the high temperature, until I press a button to reset it.

This is my coding so far:

```c
const int greenLed = 3;
const int redLed = 4;
const int yellowLed = 5;
float tempC;
int reading;
int tempPin = 0;
int speakerOut = 11;
const int buttonPin = 2;     
int buttonState = 0;     
long duration = 10000;
int tempo = 0;

void setup() {
// initialize digital pin 13 as an output.
pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
pinMode(2, INPUT);
pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
analogReference(INTERNAL);
Serial.begin(9600);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
reading = analogRead(tempPin);
tempC = reading / 9.31;
Serial.println(tempC);
delay(500);

if (tempC < 30.00) {
//Serial.println("Temp LOW");
digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
delay(10);
}else {
digitalWrite(3,LOW);
delay(10);

}

if (31.00 < tempC < 33){
//Serial.println("Temp MED");
digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
digitalWrite(5,LOW);
delay(50);
digitalWrite(4,LOW);
digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
delay(50);

}else {
digitalWrite(4,LOW);
digitalWrite(5,LOW);

}

if(tempC >= 34){
**WHAT SHOULD I FILL UP HERE TO MAKE SURE MY PIEZO BUZZER ON FOREVER**
}
if(buttonState = 1);{
digitalWrite(11, LOW);
}
```

}

Any help would be great. Or if you have a better idea on how to do this, I'm gonna love it.

Comment: Please post the wiring of this and format the code. Also use the constants you have defined. Why define "greenLed = 3" and still use "digitalWrite(3, ...)"?

Comment: uhmm i dont get what you mean.its my 1st month learning this.well if i do "greenLed =3 , it is not good to use digitalWrite(3,...)"? .Whats the better way?

Comment: A better way is "digitalWrite(greenLed, ...)". The whole idea behind giving a pin a "name" is to allow change but also make the code easier to read. But your lecturer should have told you that :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [toneAC](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/ToneAC) library, which allows even better handling of piezo speakers then the standard "tone"-functions.

> **Features:** Nearly twice the volume (because it uses two out of phase pins in push/pull fashion)
>       Higher quality (less clicking)
>       Capability of producing higher frequencies (even if running at a lower clock speed)
>       Nearly 1.5k smaller compiled code
>       Bug fixes (standard tone library can generate some odd and unpredictable results)
>       Can set not only the frequency but also the sound volume
>       Less stress on the speaker so it will last longer and sound better

With the library you can do something like:

```
int freq = 1000
int vol = 10
int length = 0
boolean background = true

toneAC(freq, vol, length, background);
```

The tone now will play forever in the background, until you stop it with:

```
toneAC(0);
```

Comment: Ohh cool.Gonna try this one later. Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 0):

1. The answer is simple add

   ```
   digitalWrite(speakerOut,HIGH);
   ```
2. Common mistake made by beginners is to use assign operator instead of compare operator

   ```
   if(buttonState=1)
   ```

   should actually be

   ```
   if(buttonState==1)
   ```
3. Never pull that pin LOW

   ```
   if(buttonState = 1);{
   digitalWrite(11, LOW);
   }
   ```

   is wrong use the below code

   ```
   if(buttonState == 1){
       digitalWrite(11, LOW);
   }
   ```

Don't forget to connect the button to buttonPin or you will get random HIGH or LOW from that pin since its floating

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's not how a Piezo-Speaker works...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35639/discussion-on-answer-by-lokanath-arduino-infinity-loop).